# How to implement event/listeners with repository pattern in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, design-patterns, listener, repository-pattern

I can't make listeners trigger action update, create or delete when I user patter repository.

Addionally I have added my code in order to help my to solve my problem.

TicketController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Organizer\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Events\Contracts\IEvent;
use App\Entities\Event;

class TicketController extends Controller
{
    protected $IEvent;

    public function __construct( IEvent $IEvent )
    {
        $this->IEvent = $IEvent;
    }

    public function checkFutbolType ($activityId)
    {   
       // I need to listen this action here
        $event = $this->IEvent->update(21927, ['title'=>'new title']);
    }

}
```

My RepoEvent.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Events\Repositories;

use App\Http\Events\Contracts\IEvent
;

class RepoEvent implements IEvent
{

    protected $model;

    public function __construct($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function update($activityId, $params)
    {
        return $this->model->where('id', $activityId)->update($params);
    }

}
```

My AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Entities\Event;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //event: creating
        Event::creating(function (Event $event) {
            return $event->creatingEvent();
        });

        //event: saving
        Event::saving(function (Event $event) {
            return $event->savingEvent();
        });

        //event: updating
        Event::updating(function (Event $event) {
            return $event->updatingEvent();
        });
    } 
}
```

My interface IEvent.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Events\Contracts;

interface IEvent
{
    public function update($activityId, $params);
}
```

My ServicesOrchestration.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Administration\Providers;

use App\Entities\Event;

use App\Http\Administration\Repositories\RepoEvent;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ServicesOrchestration extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {

    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Http\Administration\Contracts\IEvent', function () {
            return new RepoEvent(new Event());
        });
    }
}
```

My model Event.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{   
    public function creatingUser() {
        \Log::info('creating event');
    }

    public function savingUser() {
        \Log::info('saving event');
    }

    public function updatingUser() {
        \Log::info('updating event');
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.thanks in advance.thanks in advance.thanks in advance.thanks in advance.thanks in advance

Comment: We can't guess what may be wrong with your code. You need to share your code with us.

Comment: @apokryfos there you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the relevant snipped from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) (scroll to mass updates):

> When issuing a mass update via Eloquent, the `saved` and `updated` model events will not be fired for the updated models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when issuing a mass update.

For your code to work you need to first retrieve the actual model instance like below:

```
public function update($activityId, $params)
{
    $instance = $this->model->find($activityId);
    $instance->fill($params);
    $instance->save();
}
```

This will have an additional cost of doing two queries instead of one and only being able to update a single model at a time.

A sidenote: You're passing a model instance to the repository but what you actually want is to pass a query builder instance:

```
$this->app->bind('App\Http\Administration\Contracts\IEvent', function () {
    return new RepoEvent(Event::query());
});
```

Comment: Hi men, could you please explain to me why should I want to pass a query builder instance in.

Comment: `where` is a query builder method not a model method. When you call `where` it actually does create a new query builder object